# Google maps universal cross-platform syntax link doesn't initialize adresses when opening from Chrome using a Android mobile device

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, navigation, angular8

In an Angular8 application with Ionic5 I use a link to open Google Maps navigation with multiple adresses initialized in it.
I followed the official documents to construct the URL as described in:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

My function which opens the url looks like this:

```
export interface ILatLong {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
}

export interface IFromTo {
  from: ILatLong;
  to: ILatLong;
}

export interface IRoute {
  fromTo: IFromTo;
  stopovers: ILatLong[];
}

export const openFullRouteMaps = (navRoute: IRoute) => {
  const waypoints = (stops: ILatLong[]) => {
    if (stops) {
      let waypointsChained = '&waypoints=';
      for (const stop of stops) {
        waypointsChained += `${stop.latitude}%2C${stop.longitude}%7C`;
      }
      // clean up last 3 unused characters ("%7C")
      return waypointsChained.slice(0, -3);
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  };

  const win = window.open(
    `https://google.com/maps/dir/?api=1
     &origin=${navRoute.fromTo.from.latitude}%2C${navRoute.fromTo.from.longitude}
     &destination=${navRoute.fromTo.to.latitude}%2C${navRoute.fromTo.to.longitude}
     ${waypoints(navRoute.stopovers)}`
  );

  return win.focus();
};
```

It perfectly works (opens Google Maps website or application if available with adresses initialized)   from PC using Chome, IOS mobile devices, but when I use an Android mobile devices (also Chrome browser) it opens the Google Maps app without any adresses in it.

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another optional parameter to the URL solved my issue:

&travelmode=driving

Comment: Are you sure this is it? I had this issue and found that correcting my url to start with `https://www.google.com/` was the solution. Previously I was using `http://google.com/` for some reason.

Comment: @nathanb you are actualy right, I tested it again and adding/removing the 'www' prefix makes the difference. Makes more sense atleast, thanks